# Click event not working in Chrome extension options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my options page I generate some rows with an input number and a button, related to entries at chrome storage.

The problem is that the event listener i'm creating for the buttons doesn't work at all.

**options.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select the movie's Id</title>
    <style>
        body: { padding: 10px; }

        .style-1 input[type="number"] {
          padding: 10px;
          border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
          transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
          width: 5em;
        }
        .style-1 input[type="number"]:focus,
        .style-1 input[type="number"].focus {
          border: solid 1px #707070;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <legend style="border-bottom: solid 1px">Insert</legend>
    <input type="number" name="id" id="id" value="">
    <button id="save">Insert</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <legend style="border-bottom: solid 1px">Manage</legend>
    <div id="ghost" style="display: none">
        <input type="number" name="VAL">
        <button name="DEL" id="" >Delete</button>
        <br><br>
    </div>

    <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
```

**options.js**

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);

chrome.storage.sync.get('movieId', function(result){
    for (var i=0; i<result.movieId.length; i++){
       createRow(result.movieId[i]); 
    }
});

function save_options() {
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.get('movieId', function(result){
        var ids = result.movieId;
        ids.push(id);
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            'movieId': ids
        }, function() { 
        });
        location.reload();
    });    
}

function createRow(pos){
    var newRows= document.getElementById('ghost').cloneNode(true);
    newRows.id= '';
    newRows.style.display= 'block';
    var newRow= newRows.childNodes;
    for (var i= 0; i< newRow.length; i++){
        var newName= newRow[i].name;
        if (newName){
            newRow[i].name = newName+pos;
            newRow[i].id = pos;
            newRow[i].value = pos;
        }
    }
    var insertHere= document.getElementById('ghost');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newRows,insertHere);

    document.getElementById(pos).addEventListener('click', delet());
}

function loop(arrayIds){
    console.log('loop');
    for (var i=0; i<arrayIds.length; i++){
        createRow(i);
    }
}

function delet(){
    console.log("this.id");
    //chrome.storage.sync.remove(id);
}
```

With this, when I click any of the Delete buttons nothing happens.

I've tried all the combinations I can think for  `document.getElementById(pos).addEventListener('click', delet());` but none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(pos).addEventListener('click', delet());
```

is supposed to be

```
document.getElementById(pos).addEventListener('click', delet);
```

In your snippet you are calling `delet` thus result of that function is added as event listener that is `undefined`. If you want to bind `delet` as event handler, pass it to `addEventListener` without calling it.

**EDIT**

As I saw your code, you are giving same id to both `input` and `button` and when you call `document.getElementById` it returns `input` instead of `button` so, event is binded to `input` instead of `button`.

To fix that replace your `createRow` with this

```
function createRow(pos) {

    var newRow = document.getElementById('ghost').cloneNode(true);
    newRow.id= '';
    newRow.style.display= 'block';

    var value = newRow.querySelector("[name=VAL]");
    var button = newRow.querySelector("[name=DEL]");

    value.id = "VAL" + pos;
    value.value = pos;

    button.id = "DEL" + pos;

    var insertHere= document.getElementById('ghost');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, insertHere);

    button.addEventListener('click', delet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is still not working.
I've also tried with `document.getElementById(pos).addEventListener('click', function() {delet()});` and that also doesn't work.

Comment: @cargide can you please look into console for logged errors ?

Comment: The console shows nothing, and when I click the delete buttons, `console.log("this.id");` doesn't appear.

Comment: @cargide is it ok for you to share archived minimal extension with me so I can better debug the issue?

Comment: It's ok, but I am really new to this and don't know how to minify the extension.

Comment: @cargide just zip your entire extension upload that somewhere & post link here.

Comment: [Here it is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ODxhpmfJL8ZEZwclZVWWs2NTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @cargide answer updated [you can find package here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-oZ0qiCFY74WDd1MGRUU2NqSlk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Now I can try to really delete the things.